# Unexpected output in java when using ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()

Tags: java, list, arraylist, runtime-error

I have the following code in java, which takes in input from the user. It is basically a simple database system.

```
ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> blocks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

System.out.println("Enter the transaction commands.\n");

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

while(!(line = scan.nextLine()).toLowerCase().equals("end"))
{
    commands.add(line);
}

for(String com : commands)
{
    String split[] = com.split(" ");
    if(!split[0].toLowerCase().equals("get") && !split[0].toLowerCase().equals("numequalto") && !split[0].toLowerCase().equals("rollback") && !split[0].toLowerCase().equals("commit"))
    {
        if(split[0].toLowerCase().equals("begin"))
        {
            if(!list.isEmpty())
            {
                blocks.add(list);
                System.out.println(blocks.get(0));
                list.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list.add(com);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(blocks.get(0));
```

The **input** I give for this program is:

```
set a 10
set b 20
begin
get a
get b
end
```

While the **expected output** is:

```
[set a 10, set b 20]
[set a 10, set b 20]
```

I get the **output** as:

```
[set a 10, set b 20]
[]
```

The problem seems to be that the value of the **ArrayList> blocks**, seems to be overwritten. The last print statement prints the value as an empty ArrayList. I cannot find the exact source of error. Any help in finding out the error will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following code is the culprit:

```
blocks.add(list);
System.out.println(blocks.get(0));
list.clear();
```

You add the list to blocks. Note, when you are adding your list object to blocks, you are not copying the list.

So when you clear the list, it clears the list object that is also referenced in the blocks list.

To avoid this you could just:

```
blocks.add(list);
System.out.println(blocks.get(0));
list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This will create a new list object and leave the one in your blocks list untouched.

Answer (score 3):

Your second output is got from last line of `System.out.println(blocks.get(0));`. Have a look at your code, you add `blocks.add(list);` after a while you `clear` the `list`. As `List` is mutable, so `blocks` `List` is empty. So, your second output print nothing.

```
 blocks.add(list); //list has added here with values
 System.out.println(blocks.get(0));
 list.clear();  // list here without values.
```

Comment: Doesn't the line 

blocks.add(list);

do that?

Comment: Yes. After addition, you clear list as well as block list. Because, List is mutable.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed that one.! :)

Answer (score 1):

This giving correct answer as you expected.

remove that  `list.clear()` statement

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> blocks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Enter the transaction commands.\n");
        String line;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!(line = scan.nextLine()).toLowerCase().equals("end")) {
            commands.add(line);
        }

        for (String com : commands) {
            String split[] = com.split(" ");
            if (!split[0].toLowerCase().equals("get")
                    && !split[0].toLowerCase().equals("numequalto")
                    && !split[0].toLowerCase().equals("rollback")
                    && !split[0].toLowerCase().equals("commit")) {
                if (split[0].toLowerCase().equals("begin")) {
                    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                        blocks.add(list);
                        System.out.println("list :" + blocks.get(0));
                        // list.clear();
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    list.add(com);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("output :" + blocks.get(0));
    }

}
```

Answer i got is

```
list :[set a 10, set b 20]
output :[set a 10, set b 20]
```